# Citation `XXXX' on page YY undefined in VS Code

Tags: bibtex, citing, visual-studio-code, vscode

I've recently started working on my first LaTeX document and I'm doing it in VSCode. I have the LaTeX workshop plugin installed and it's worked flawlessly until now.

I have my basic .tex document with some text and the following structure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{11.05.2021}
    
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\cite{rachmadi}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

And the References.bib file which looks like:

```
@misc{rachmadi,
author = {Rachmadi,Reza F. and Uchimura,Keiichi and Komokata,Yoshinori},
year={2016},
month={Jan 01,},
title={Japan road sign classification using cascade convolutional neural network},
journal={23 rd ITS World Congress},
pages={10},
language={English},
url={https://explore.openaire.eu/search/publication?articleId=datacite____::203929aafebe8a9e65d676b893571658},
}
```

I can't find any discrepancies in the way I've written this and yet I'm getting this error:

> Citation `rachmadi' on page 1 undefined.

I've tried building the project with Recipe: pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex x2, I've tried deleting the .log and .bbl files and rebuilding, but nothing seems to work. In the generated PDF the citation just looks like a question mark, but the source appears in the references section.

How do I make it so the citation appears as a "[number]" instead of the question mark, and how do I get rid of the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the issue, but the `_` character creates some problem. Try replacing it with `\_`.